# Is it possible to provide an Internet connection to my mobile through a USB modem?

Tags: internet, mobile-broadband

I have a Huawei USB modem with an Internet connection. I want that Internet connection to be available to my mobile. My mobile has WiFi, 3G, GPRS and EDGE. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/), you can share your wired internet connection with your mobile phone through WiFi. You need a PC with Windows 7 to achieve that.

Comment: Got exactly Windows 7 Laptop :D

Comment: @Rajasekar: Did you try it?